# SQL Database tables

Tags: php, sql, database, phpmyadmin

I was hoping someone can help me out. I created some tables using the SQL file and not phpmyadmin and I'm hoping to upload them but needed some clarification if I did it right. Here is my code:

```
-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Table structure for table `agents`
--

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `agents`;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `agents` (
   `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
   `first name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
   `last name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
   `company` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
   `associations` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
   `agent type` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
   `address – get directions` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
   `State` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
   `county` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
   `city` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
   `zip code` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
   `office phone number` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
   `office fax number` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
   `cell / txt number` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
   `email` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
   `website` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
   `social media profiles` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
   `license #` varchar(255) NOT NULL,                          
   `realtor since` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
   `biography` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
   `experience` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
   `awards - certifications` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
   `affiliations` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
   `languages` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
   `practice areas` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
   `hobbies - interests` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
   `featured properties` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
   `contact form` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=8 ;
```

I didn't know if the space between first and name should be included as well and I also didn't know if I have the Varchar numbers correct as well.

Answer (score 1):

Depends on how much space you are looking for.  This will in theory get your table created, but not very efficiently.  May go back and edit the lengths of your fields to be more applicable to what is in them.  Dont really need 255 characters for state and county.

I don't believe 'hobbies - interests' and  is going to be a valid column name and generally would stick to one word or no space names if it will just be in the background so it is quicker to write queries upon.

Lot easier to type out fname instead of [first name]

Might also be a good idea to clean up the other symbols to make your code a little cleaner and easier to move around when building future queries.

Comment: I don't think VARCHAR fields reserve space for the maximum size, so there's little performance overhead from setting them to 255. It uses the maximum to determine how many bytes to use for the length field, so going above 255 will waste an extra byte, since a 2-byte length field will be required, but that's it.

Comment: Thanks Barmar...I am used to using the smallest possible solution so I always gun shy away when I see anything over 2 spaces for the state.  Would another datatype work better here?

Comment: For fields where everything is the same length, like states, `CHAR(2)` is best because it doesn't need a length byte.

Comment: How about this: `first_name` varchar(35) NOT NULL,
   `last_name` varchar(35) NOT NULL,
   `company` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
   `associations` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
   `agent_type` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
   `address_directions` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
   `State` varchar(35) NOT NULL,
   `county` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
   `city` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
   `zip` varchar(35) NOT NULL,
   `office_phone number` varchar(35) NOT NULL,
   `office_fax number` varchar(35) NOT NULL,
   `cell_txt number` varchar(35) NOT NULL,
   `email` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
   `website` varchar(255) NOT NULL,

Answer (score 0):

Don't use any spaces. use first_name instead. Also, zip instead of zip code, definitely no dashes and slashes in field types like you have in cell / text number and awards - certification.

For easier coding use one word field names if possible and if not separate them by underscore. Nobody will see field names but you and any other developer doing that site in case you are working in team environment.

Comment: Using backticks allow you to use almost any character in a column name. It just means that you always have to use backticks, which results in lots of ugly code.

Comment: @Barmar Yes you are completely right. And I never meant it would not work but i would strongly recommend not to use it because of the same reason - messy code and not as easy to write.